# Iphone running out of battery kills app

Tags: ios, fatal-error, battery

I'm close to completing my first app and I just discovered a potentially devastating issue. When the battery ran out on my iPhone my app would not open after recharge. Whatever happened, it appears to have been fatal. I was able to recreate the error on another iPhone as well.

Can anyone help me? I have found very little about this on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to me that you store some data for your app on the device. And this data is in incorrect state after the recharge. Try to figure it out and rewrite data saving code.